# How can I scrape a facebook page for the date of upload of the video

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, automation

I need help with scraping a facebook video page for the date of the upload of video.

Check this link as a sample video:https://www.facebook.com/158451774498354/videos/270140270537510/

Here 20 April 2019 is the date of upload.
I want to access it using beautiful soup and python.
I tried various methods but I wasn't able to access this specific area.
It would be really helpful if someone can provide me with a function for the same.

```
def find_date(url):
    page = requests.get(url) 
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.text,"lxml")
    l = []
#     print(soup)
    for links in soup.find_all("span",{"class":"timestampContent"}):
        print(links.text)
        l.append(links.text)
#     print(l[7])
```

I wrote this small function for the same but it scrapes all the dates in the page except the upload date of the video playing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Developer tools(Ctrl+Shift+I) and use Select of element with mouse cursor (Ctrl+Shift+C) so you could locate DOCTYPE XTML and use It class to be able to scrape it with Beautiful Soup.

[image: There is your access point to your data]

I wont write whole code for you, You gave none of your code and it's not the way to learn coding, so please upload your code and errors and I will guide you. Also you can check the scraper I've done for jobs offering site on my [GitHub](https://github.com/evaninas/VCSproject/blob/master/cvbankas%20scraper).

Comment: Sir!
I have edited the statement and added the code which I tried. It would be really helpful if you can guide me on the errors I made.

Answer (score 0):

so by your given Code I tried to edit it and run.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.facebook.com/gaoxuelinji/videos/270140270537510/?v=270140270537510'
page = requests.get(url) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content,'html.parser')
l = []
#     print(soup)
for links in soup.find_all("span",class_='timestampContent'):
    print(links.text)
```

Which does not gives me outcome you want. In fact it doesn't event contain date it was originally created.

```
Liepos 8 d.
Liepos 5 d.
Vasario 21 d.
2019 m. rugpjūčio 10 d.
2019 m. rugpjūčio 10 d.
2019 m. rugpjūčio 5 d.
2019 m. liepos 28 d.
2019 m. liepos 28 d.
2019 m. liepos 22 d.
```

So I suggest you give your self a bit of time while reading HTML and BS https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/